# How do I stop other videos from showing on my embedded youtube video when it is finished instead of just going back to the thumbnail image?

Tags: youtube, embed

There was a time when I used the embed code from a YouTube video I created, loaded it onto a website page, and when the video stopped at the end, it reverted right back to the thumbnail image ... For some reason, this has stopped, and I always see suggested videos "for me", because they are one's I either watched before, or they are suggested by YT ...

I found a code in a search, but when I put that in, instead of the original code, my video didn't work ...